# Does ionization energy play a role in absorption spectrometry of non metals?

Tags: absorption

Absorption spectrometry is useful for analysing metals in the samples. But it's not recomended for non metals though. I know that it's difficult to analyse non metals because most of them absorbs in the same wavelenght as atmosphere (oxygen). Anyway, I would like to know if ionization energy plays a role in this analytical technique. I can't find any strong source.

Answer (score 3):

Your intuitive argument is not that far off. I am sure you are talking about atomic absorption spectrometry (AAS). Analyzing metals is routine but analyzing non-metals is indeed near impossible because one has to work in the vacuum UV region, but some non-metals like phosphorous can be determined with very low sensitivity (=large detection limits). Indirect methods for non-metals exist though.

The main point to remember in AAS is that you want free atoms *not* ions. So nobody is interested in ionizing metals or non-metals (hence their ionization energy), rather it is desired that ionization be suppressed in AAS using ionization suppression buffers. What one is interested in AAS in the *electronic transition from the ground state to the first excited state*. Ionization is far far away.

Look at this data from Perkin Elmer's AAS Cookbook for P, and its corresponding harsh conditions to even atomize phosphorous. A nitrous oxide is flame is required.

[image]

Comment: So the argument of ionization energy is invalid. It all makes sense now.

Comment: I think so. There is Saha equation that talks about ionization but that is for stars but some people did connect to flame spectroscopy as well. I studied this decades ago.